# Why is this situation caused when I put border-bottom?

Tags: css, border, h2, underline

I code gray colored border-bottom property at a tag in h2 tag.
But as attached video file, black line and gray line is mixed.
I have no idea why this is occured. text-decoration:none is adapted.

[image]

```css
h2 a:hover {border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to a page where this is present?

Comment: Hello chloe, welcome to this site. Create an MVCE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, this is expected from you when you ask questions on StackOverflow.